# Is it possible to tell if any changes was made to a mongodb database, using the oplog?

Tags: mongodb

My object is to improve the performance of our integration tests. This made me think if it would be possible to detect if any changes was made to MongoDB?

We run our tests against the in-memory MongoDB server, and in the `beforeEach` hook I would therefore like to prune+seed the database, but only if any changes occurred. Our in-memory database uses replica set, and we use transactions.

**What I wan't**

A way to determine if there had been any changes (insert, update, delete) to our database.

**What I have tried**

I tried using a count on the oplog, using the aggregation framework:

```
{
  $match: {
    ns: /<db-name>/,
    op: { $in: ['u', 'i', 'd'] },
  },
},
{ $count: 'count' },
```

This does not seem to work.

I also tried to just query the latest oplog document, and save the `ui` binary field, and compare later. However, it seems like this ID can stay the same, despite what I define as changes happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tail oplog to check changes , but the better option introduced in mongodb 3.6 and above is to use change streams:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams

example watching changes in real time  made in exampleDB database from console mongo client:

```
 watchCursor = db.getSiblingDB("exampledb").watch()

 while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
   if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
       printjson(watchCursor.next());
    }
 }
```

You can also watch changes at collection level as follow:

```
  watchCursor = db.getSiblingDB("exampleDB").exampleCOL.watch()

  while (!watchCursor.isExhausted()){
      if (watchCursor.hasNext()){
      printjson(watchCursor.next());
  }
 }
```

Comment: Only issue that I now have is that the `watch()` starts again when jest restarts... So I end up having multiple change streams open at the same time

Comment: check this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54614760/mongodb-change-stream-timeouts-if-database-is-down-for-some-time

Comment: Thanks for link, seems more related for how you keep the change alive when errors happens. My issue is that I have multiple change streams listening, when jest restarts a test (for example when I change a test-file). But I will look into it - thanks for helping out 